# Ajax not returning JSON data

Tags: jquery, sql, json, ajax, groovy

I'm trying to perform a simple Ajax request that will call to a groovy script and return the JSON string that the script produces

here is my **Ajax:**

```
var myUrl = "connections.groovy";

$.ajax({
    url : myUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    success : function(results) {
        console.log(results)
    }
});
```

The following groovy script is used to collect the JSON from a database and to return it to the html page

**connections.groovy**

```
def cellTabel() {

    def db = [url:'jdbc:mysql://###.##.#.##', user:'###', password:'###', driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']
    def resultset = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver).rows('SELECT count(*) as NumberOfRecords,work_station,sum(marshalled) as marshalled,sum(picked) as picked, sum(complete) as complete FROM vantec.document_header where date_created >= CURRENT_DATE() and work_station != "" group by work_station')
    return new JsonBuilder(resultset).toString()
}

cellTabel();
```

If I run the groovy code by it's self in a groovy console it works and produces the JSON code I'm looking for but when I run it from the ajax on the page I get nothing back

this is the JSON I am expecting back

```
[{"NumberOfRecords":10,"work_station":"CELL1","marshalled":10,"picked":10,"complete":10},{"NumberOfRecords":19,"work_station":"CELL2","marshalled":19,"picked":19,"complete":19},{"NumberOfRecords":10,"work_station":"CELL3","marshalled":10,"picked":10,"complete":10},{"NumberOfRecords":10,"work_station":"CELL4","marshalled":10,"picked":10,"complete":10},{"NumberOfRecords":6,"work_station":"CELL5","marshalled":6,"picked":6,"complete":6},{"NumberOfRecords":1,"work_station":"CELL6","marshalled":0,"picked":1,"complete":1},{"NumberOfRecords":9,"work_station":"CELL7","marshalled":1,"picked":7,"complete":7},{"NumberOfRecords":1,"work_station":"CELL8","marshalled":0,"picked":1,"complete":1},{"NumberOfRecords":10,"work_station":"CELL9A","marshalled":6,"picked":9,"complete":9},{"NumberOfRecords":9,"work_station":"CELL9B","marshalled":6,"picked":8,"complete":8}]
```

That is the JSON I get back when I run the connections.groovy in a groovy console

**Edit:**
Response in the console 
[image: console response]
Network Tab Open
[image: network tab]

Comment: and you get call hit the method on backend ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh sorry I don't fully understand your question

Comment: SO the Ajax call you are making does it call the correct function which return the   i.e cellTabel1() . You can can you network tab as well to see request details

Comment: @YashveerSingh yes this is the only method on the connections page at the moment so as soon as it call the page it runs that method

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I get no errors in the console

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request is being made? Have you checked it in the network tab of the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is definitely being made the connections.groovy is in the network tab and in the console i just get an empty response from the console.log in the ajax **see edit**

Comment: Show the network tab with the call to 'connections.groovy' opened. How even this file exposed on a webserver?

Comment: @Strelok added picture of network tab

Comment: Have you tried to set up the accept in the header of the request to json or the dataType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your groovlet to:

```
// other stuff
def cellTabel() {

    def db = [url:'jdbc:mysql://###.##.#.##', user:'###', password:'###', driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']
    def resultset = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver).rows('SELECT count(*) as NumberOfRecords,work_station,sum(marshalled) as marshalled,sum(picked) as picked, sum(complete) as complete FROM vantec.document_header where date_created >= CURRENT_DATE() and work_station != "" group by work_station')
    return new JsonBuilder(resultset).toString()
}

response.contentType = 'application/json'
println cellTabel()
```